# How to solve designer:mapid="12r" problems in my asp.net website

Tags: asp.net, html, css

When I create new web pages from my master page then in new page `_designer:map id="34c"` appeared  in all `tr`, `table`, etc. tags. What is this?

After some days before this problem was not appeared. But today this occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I know but it is very lengthy process .you can only remove it with regular expression please go to your source code and press ctrl+f and press on replace and put regular expression and click on replace all .